# How do I replace infoLabel description with a Poster image?

Tags: brightscript

I need to convert a code like the following so that "infoLabel" will show a picture instead of text.

This code reads from an XML string that had a field id of 'posteruri' instead of 'description'

I have and example of the working script with the Label/description.  And my attempt to convert to a poster, which does not work.

My attempt doesn't return an error, however nothing shows but a blank rectangle.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<component name="categoryinfoPanel" extends="Panel" >

<interface>
   <field id="description" type="string" onChange="showdescription" /> 
</interface>

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[

sub init()
  m.top.panelSize = "medium"
  m.top.focusable = true
  m.top.hasNextPanel = true

  m.infolabel = m.top.findNode("infoLabel")
end sub

sub showdescription()
  m.infolabel.text = m.top.description 
end sub

]]> 
</script>

<children>

<Rectangle
  id = "infoRectangle"
  translation = "[0,40]"
  height = "420"
  width = "520"
  color = "0x00000099" >

  <Label
    id = "infoLabel"
    translation = "[15,15]"
    height = "595"
    width = "510"
    wrap = "true"
    font = "font:MediumBoldSystemFont" />

</Rectangle>

</children>

</component>
```

I have tried simply replacing the field id, and replacing Label with Poster at the bottom to no avail.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<component name="categoryinfoPoster" extends="Panel" >

<interface>
   <field id="posteruri" type="string" onChange="showdescription" /> 
</interface>

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[

sub init()
  m.top.panelSize = "medium"
  m.top.focusable = true
  m.top.hasNextPanel = true

  m.infoposter= m.top.findNode("infoPoster")
end sub

sub showdescription()
  m.infoposter.uri = m.top.poster 
end sub

]]> 
</script>

<children>

<Rectangle
 id = "infoRectangle"
 translation = "[0,40]"
  height = "420"
  width = "520"
  color = "0x00000099" >

  <Label
    id = "infoPoster"
    translation = "[15,15]"
    height = "400"
    width = "510" />

</Rectangle>

</children>

</component>
```

Currently text shows up onChange.  I would like for an image to show up `onChange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<component name="categoryinfoPoster" extends="Panel" >

<interface>
   <field id="posteruri" type="string" onChange="showdescription" /> 
</interface>

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[

sub init()
  m.top.panelSize = "medium"
  m.top.focusable = true
  m.top.hasNextPanel = true

  m.infoposter= m.top.findNode("infoPoster")
end sub

sub showdescription()
  m.infoposter.uri = m.top.poster 
end sub

]]> 
</script>

<children>

<Rectangle
 id = "infoRectangle"
 translation = "[0,40]"
  height = "420"
  width = "520"
  color = "0x00000099" >

  <Poster
    id = "infoPoster"
    translation = "[15,15]"
    height = "400"
    width = "510" />

</Rectangle>

</children>

</component>
```

You need to replace "Label" node with "poster" node in "rectangle" node.
It looks like You did everything except that. So You are passing "uri" to a "label" node and that's why you did not see the image.
I also assume that You got some error in the debugger because of it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Good catch.  I forgot to update the infoPoster under the last node.  Another thing to note is that only hdposterurl or sdposterurl works for the field id when you use screnegraph.  I had to change posteruri to hdposterurl.  I will add the working code in my next post.  Thanks or the help.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the full code that worked for me.  Thanks to U.Mitic for catching my error in the PosterNode.  And remember if you use scenegraph templates.  Only HDPosterUrl or SDPosterURL will work for poster in the field ID.

''''

```
<component name="categoryinfoPoster" extends="Panel" >

<interface>
   <field id="hdposterurl" type="string" onChange="showdescription" /> 
</interface>

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[

sub init()
  m.top.panelSize = "medium"
  m.top.focusable = true
  m.top.hasNextPanel = true

  m.infoposter= m.top.findNode("infoPoster")
end sub

sub showdescription()
  m.infoposter.uri = m.top.hdposterurl
end sub

]]> 
</script>

<children>

<Rectangle
 id = "infoRectangle"
 translation = "[0,40]"
  height = "420"
  width = "520"
  color = "0x00000099" >

  <Poster
    id = "infoPoster"
    translation = "[15,15]"
    height = "400"
    width = "510" />

</Rectangle>

</children>

</component>
```

''''